# How do I ask management to find my replacement quickly and shorten my notice period?

Tags: interviewing, india

Currently am working at a Company for more than 2 years . 
I have applied for resignation . 
Company is in search for candidates .

I am already approaching my notice period (63 out of 90 days) .

How should I ask management to do the interview process rapidly and get a new candidate ASAP so I can leave before the end of my notice period?

Comment: Am from Hyderabad, India .Yes may be you are right . It's not compulsory .My intention is to get out of my Company ASAP .But this thing totally changed almost everything .

Comment: Which country are you in? Your boss may or may not be able to make this a requirement. Training someone to take over your job is certainly part of what a notice period is for, but finding that person is normally management's responsibility, and more often it's a matter if finding someone internally as a stopgap and hiring the replacement layer. Having said that, if they have a candidate it is ___entirely___ reasonable for them to have you do a technical interview and tell them whether you think this person can do the job; that responsibility comes with not being a clueless newbie.

Comment: I do not understand India's employment systwm; I can't help much.

Comment: Is there anything in your employment contract about this? If you hire someone incompetent by mistake because you are rushed for time and inexperienced at hiring, is there any possible recourse against you? Are you depending on severance pay, or a good reference which they could withhold if you refuse or avoid doing this? Particularly "*I have applied for resignation*" and "*.. only then I should leave the Company*" seem strange - do you need permission to leave, can your boss force you to stay? (Do you have a fixed start date for whatever you are doing next?)

Comment: I can leave whenever I want but certificates of experience is some thing I might miss . It will be my second AWOL in my career .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately my understanding is employers in India have a great deal of control because of relieving letters. So in your case I would at least go through the motions of complying. It seems unlikely that you could teach a replacement in such a short time, but if your job is well documented that is normally enough.

So I would suggest you talk to your boss about allocating time to document your tasks properly just in case a replacement is not found and fully trained in time..

Answer (score 3):

I can't address cultural differences so bear that in mind.

Your job isn't as a recruiter. Your job is the job for which you were hired.  Basically your boss is being lazy. Just because you know how to do a job doesn't mean you know how to find someone else who does.

You should (in my opinion) push back on the hiring but say that you'd be glad to train the replacement (if that's indeed the case).  The company is more suited to do hiring than you are.

Comment: For a moment I thought to go forward by posting on a career site . I already took standard job description details . But now I should discuss with my Boss again .

Comment: "That's not my job" is a horrible reason to not do something at work.

Comment: Read it again. "Just because you know how to do a job doesn't mean you know how to find someone else who does". The reason not to do something that isn't your job is for the very (I thought) obvious reason that you aren't really qualified to do it. If my employer tried to get me to manage a project, I would "push back" (which is what I said in my answer) because that's not what I do. I'm a software engineer, not a PM. Completely different skill sets. There's a reason not to do someone else's job when you're not qualified to do it. It would hurt the company. That' why he should push back.